# Decoding error,image format unsupported Azure

Tags: android, flask, javax.imageio, httpconnection, azure-cognitive-services

I am running a flask server at the backend. I want to read the image from mobile app and send it to the server to detect faces.

This is the java code(client side) for sending image as bytes -

```
public class client {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/facial";
// 2. create obj for the URL class
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        // 3. open connection on the url
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","image/jpeg");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);


        try {

            System.out.println("Reading image from disk. ");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            baos.flush();
            File file = new File("jpeg.jpg");
            BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(file);

            ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            System.out.println(baos.size());
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();

            System.out.println("Sending image to server. ");

            OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream image = new DataOutputStream(out);

            image.writeInt(bytes.length);
            image.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            System.out.println("Image sent to server. ");

            image.close();
            // close the output stream
            out.close();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // define object for the reply from the server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        //Get response from server
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        // read in the response from the server
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        // close the input stream
        in.close();

    }

}
```

This is my server code -

```
def get_facial(data):
    face_api_url = 'https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'

    # Set image_url to the URL of an image that you want to analyze.
    headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream"
    }
    params = {
        'returnFaceId': 'true',
        'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
        'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,' +
        'emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise'
    }
    response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
    faces = response.json()
    res={}
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    res["status"] = '200'
    res["num"] = str(len(faces))
    return res

@app.route('/facial',methods=['POST'])
def facial():
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    data=bytes(request.get_data())
    res={}
    try:
        res = get_facial(data)
    except:
        res['status'] = '404'
    print(res)
    return json.dumps(res)
```

After examining - I sent the **same image** from another **python file** and checked the size of the data. It was 102564 bytes and **it works** but
the same image read and sent from java code is 106208 bytes. I don't know where exactly the mistake is.
Any help is appreciated !!:-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick fix to this problem -

```
Path path = Paths.get("jpeg.jpg");
byte[] fileContents =  Files.readAllBytes(path);
image.write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.length);
```

I don't exactly know why reading from imageio fails. My guess is that its also reading the file headers of the jpg file.

Comment: I think this is a sound solution, as it doesn't unnecessarily decode and encode the JPEG again. This (the re-encoding) is what caused the file to be bigger. The problem of your original code though, was probably that you prepended the file with the file length.